# How to get query string value once page is insert data and redirect t the older page

Tags: php

Once I perform insert operation(insertProcess.php), page insert detail and then redirect to the same older (insertdetail.php) page.
I set a query string variable in insertdetail.php, after inserting data page is redirect to insertdetail.php but query string value is lost...
how can i retrive it

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keQ9b.png)

Comment: Please provide sample code and a proper description of what you expect to happen.
See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To be able to help you, we need to see the code and the image you provided is rally not helpful for us to understand your issue.
But from the description that you provided, maybe the following comment is helpful.
Whenever redirect to a php file or reload it all of the data stored in the variables are lost. To keep the data you need to use SESSIONS or use the include() or require() functions.

Comment: Next time I will provide such code for reference.Thanks for the answer...

Comment: @KishanGadoya You can edit this question with your code.

Comment: @mulquin Sure for next doubt,I am fresh user of stachoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your description the page you wan to redirect accepts a query string in url, so whenever you call that page just add a query string after that page's url...

```
insertdetail.php?variable=value
```

Hope this works :)

Answer (score 1):

Exact answer:       header('location:../insertDetail.php?blk='.$block);

?blk = ; .$block);return the exact querystring